# Docker Tutorial Unclear: "Persisting our DB" and "Using Bind Mounts"

Tags: docker, directory, path, documentation

I have only started using **Docker** and was trying to follow the documentation on the official website... Everything was going smoothly until I got to [this](http://localhost/tutorial/persisting-our-data/) point.
In step 3: [image: step 3 of docker tutorial - Persisting our DB]
Upon running the command, I get this error -> **ls: cannot access 'C:/Program Files/Git/': No such file or directory.**

I thought it was not that big of a deal so I went ahead and skipped to the following parts of the tutorial.
Then I came across the same error in [this](http://localhost/tutorial/using-bind-mounts/) part:
[image: step 2 and 3 Docker Tutorial - Using bind Mounts]

I tried to locate the directory on my PC manually and found a remote git repository, but the commands still don't work for me. These were the commands that I have tried and their corresponding errors:

`docker run -it ubuntu ls /` - No such file or directory

`cd /path/to/getting-started/app` - No such file or directory

`` docker run -dp 3000:3000 ` -w /app -v "$(pwd):/app" ` node:12-alpine ` sh -c "yarn install && yarn run dev" `` - docker: Error response from daemon: the working directory 'C:/Program Files/Git/app' is invalid, it needs to be an absolute path.
See 'docker run --help'. *(this error was after changing to the directory I manually searched on my PC)*

I'm unsure if I have to set a PATH??? I don't think I have missed any of the steps provided in the earlier tutorials.

Comment: I would suggest that you create a new folder like C.\development and cd into that. Then for your project a new folder in there. Right now you're in your git installation folder where you shouldn't be

Comment: The thing is I downloaded the app from the tutorial and have been running commands from there. Only this time, my command didn't work which is why I tried to search for the specified path in the command itself.  I tried running the same command in the project directory, but got the same error message.

Comment: which cli are you using? Maybe this is your problem https://github.com/docker-archive/toolbox/issues/673

Comment: Sounds like you are using the git bash which comes packages with git scm for windows. I strongly recommend to avoid this and switch to WSL2. The git bash is NOT the kind of shell you are looking for when using docker due to missing libs and nasty side effects which are mostly very hard to debug.

Comment: Thanks, guys! I was indeed using git bash on VSCode. I tried running it on my Windows terminal via ubuntu and now, everything's working fine. Thanks, Max, and Spears. Exactly what I was having issues with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, guys! I was indeed using git bash on VSCode. I tried running it on my Windows terminal via ubuntu and now, everything's working fine. Thanks, Max, and Spears. Exactly what I was having issues with.

These comments helped me resolve the issue:

> Maybe this is your problem github.com/docker-archive/toolbox/issues/673 –
> Max

> Sounds like you are using the git bash which comes packages with git scm for >windows. I strongly recommend to avoid this and switch to WSL2. The git bash >is NOT the kind of shell you are looking for when using docker due to missing >libs and nasty side effects which are mostly very hard to debug. - Spears